# Left join on single record

Tags: sql, postgresql, hana

I have the next table that stores events:
(simplified structure)

| ID | User | Action | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | user1 | END | 2022-01-01 05:00 |
| 43 | user1 | START | 2022-01-01 04:00 |
| 54 | user1 | END | 2022-01-01 03:00 |
| 13 | user1 | START | 2022-01-01 02:00 |

I need to join 2 events in one row, so any START event is accompanied by the END event that comes after that.

So the result should be the next:

| ID1 | ID2 | User | Start Timestamp | End Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 54 | user1 | 2022-01-01 02:00 | 2022-01-01 03:00 |
| 43 | 12 | user1 | 2022-01-01 04:00 | 2022-01-01 05:00 |

Ideally, it should not have to many performance issues, as there could be a lot of records in the table.

I've tried the next query:

```
select 
  s.id as "ID1",
  e.id as "ID2",
  s.user,
  s.time as "Start Time",
  e.time as "End Time"
from Events s
left join Events e on s.user = e.user
where s.action = 'START'
  and e.action = 'END'
  and s.timestamp < e.timestamp
```

but it will also match the record 13 to record 12.
Is it possible to join the left side to right only once? (keeping in mind that is should be the next END record time-wise?

Thanks

Comment: May be https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms will help you

Comment: Use `inner join`. :)

Comment: Do you only have the time or also the date (or datetime)?

Comment: Will a time ever cross midnight?

Comment: How do you match START and END values?

Comment: @Natrium it's timestamp - edited.

Comment: @jarlh Basically for each START record for a user I need to get the next END record for the same.

Comment: @subhamX I don't think that will work. that will not show show the START records that have not ENDed yet. It will also not solve the issue with extra matching

Comment: SAP HANA or Postgres? Please do not add tags for databases not involved

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ideally it should be sql query that works for both. But if it's not possible - 2 different queries: one for hana and one for postgres

Comment: @PavloZasiadko ah. my bad. I misread the question. I think the data modelling is to blame here. For, every start time we're bound to match all the end time unless there is a specific id which does this mapping. Instead we can do the following: `For every row with START get the row which is closest with END (or keep it null)`. This is definitely not foolproof, as I'm making a big assumption.

Comment: Yes @subhamX, that seems accurate. Except the closest END row has to be in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is a lateral join that picks the smallest "end" timestamp that is greater than the "start" timestamp:

```
select st.id as id1,
       en.id as id2,
       st."timestamp" as start_timestamp,
       en."timestamp" as end_timestamp
from events st
  left join lateral (
      select id, "timestamp"
      from events e
      where e."user" = st."user" 
        and e.action = 'END'
      and e.timestamp >= st.timestamp
      order by "timestamp" 
      fetch first 1 row only
  ) en on true
where st.action = 'START';
```

The above is standard ANSI SQL and works (at least) in Postgres.

In Postgres I would create an index on `events ("user", "timestamp") where action = 'END'` to make the lateral query fast.

Comment: Thanks, that worked good for postgres. For hana I had to replace `on true` with one of the conditions from the where clause of the inner query (e.g. `e.user = st.user`), as apparently such syntax is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a PostgreSQL solution using lateral join. It *might* be working on HANA as no Postgres-specific features are used. The internal query selects  the 'END' action for the same user that occurred soonest after the corresponding 'START'. Events that have started but not finished yet will have NULL values for "ID2" and "End timestamp".

```sql
create temporary table the_table(id integer, usr text, action text, ts timestamp);
insert into the_table values 
(12,'user1','END','2022-01-01 05:00'),(43,'user1','START','2022-01-01 04:00'),
(54,'user1','END','2022-01-01 03:00'),(13,'user1','START','2022-01-01 02:00');

select tx.id as "ID1", l.id as "ID2", tx.usr as "User", 
       tx.ts as "Start timestamp", l.ts as "End timestamp" 
from the_table as tx
left join lateral 
(
  select ti.id, ti.ts
  from the_table as ti 
  where ti.action = 'END' 
    and ti.ts > tx.ts 
    and ti.usr = tx.usr
  order by ti.ts - tx.ts
  limit 1
) as l on true  
where tx.action = 'START'
order by "Start timestamp";
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your query above is that for each start event, there can be multiple end events, which occur after. However, you would like to choose the one that's 'closest' to the start event. You can achieve this by adding an additional aggregation.

Please find a HANA example (uses no HANA specific functionality):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (ID integer, USER NVARCHAR(20), ACTION NVARCHAR(20), TIMESTAMP DATETIME)

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (12, 'user1', 'END', '2022-01-01 05:00')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (43, 'user1', 'START', '2022-01-01 04:00')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (54, 'user1', 'END', '2022-01-01 03:00')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (13, 'user1', 'START', '2022-01-01 02:00')

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (13, 'user1', 'START', '2022-01-01 09:00')

SELECT
    S.ID ID1,
    S.USER,
    S.ACTION,
    S.TIMESTAMP START_TIME,
    MIN(E.TIMESTAMP) END_TIME
FROM TEST S
JOIN TEST E ON (
    s.USER = e.USER AND
    s.ACTION = 'START' AND
    e.ACTION = 'END' AND
    e.TIMESTAMP >= s.TIMESTAMP
)
GROUP BY S.ID, S.ACTION, S.USER, S.TIMESTAMP
```

If you need to have `E.ID` included, you will need to join it back to the result set. Note, that there may be multiple end events with the same timestamp, which you need to handle when joining back `E.ID`.

If you additionally would like to include `START` events without corresponding `END` event, you can use the following:

```
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (13, 'user1', 'START', '2022-01-01 09:00')

SELECT
    S.ID ID1,
    S.USER,
    S.ACTION,
    S.TIMESTAMP START_TIME,
    MIN(E.TIMESTAMP) END_TIME
FROM TEST S
LEFT JOIN TEST E ON (
    s.USER = e.USER AND
    e.ACTION = 'END' AND
    e.TIMESTAMP >= s.TIMESTAMP
)
WHERE s.ACTION ='START'
GROUP BY S.ID, S.ACTION, S.USER, S.TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 0):

We want to **get the nearest timestamp of the `END` event for each `START` event.**

I would go with the following approach:

1. Get the minimum greater than zero **timestamp difference** for each of the `START` events.
2. Now find the actual `END` event using the `timedelta`.

#### Assumptions

1. At max we can have only one event which is not ended yet!
2. For every `START` event, the timestamps will be unique. (Same goes for `END` event.

```sql
WITH closest_to_start AS (
    SELECT 
        s.id,
        MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.timestamp, e.timestamp)) AS min_delta
    FROM Events AS s
    INNER JOIN Events AS e ON s.user = e.user
    WHERE s.action = 'START'
    AND e.action = 'END'
    GROUP BY s.id
    HAVING min_delta >= 0
)
SELECT s.id, 
    e.id
FROM Events AS s
OUTER JOIN closest_to_start ON closest_to_start.id = s.id
OUTER JOIN Events AS e ON e.id = s.id
WHERE s.action = 'START'
AND e.action = 'END'
AND 
(
    e.timestamp IS NULL
    OR
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s.timestamp, e.timestamp) = closest_to_start.min_delta
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window function Lead.

```
with Daten 
as
(
Select 12 as ID, 'user1' as Benutzer, 'END' as action, '05:00' as Time
Union
Select 43 as ID, 'user1' as Benutzer, 'Start' as action, '04:00' as Time
Union
Select 54 as ID, 'user1' as Benutzer, 'END' as action, '03:00' as Time
Union
Select 13 as ID, 'user1' as Benutzer, 'Start' as action, '02:00' as Time
)
Select 
    *
from
    (
        Select
            *,
            lead(ID,1) over (order by number) as ID2,
            lead(action,1) over (order by number) as action2,
            lead(time,1) over (order by number) as time2
        from
            (
                Select 
                    *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Benutzer,Time,action) as number
                from
                     Daten
            ) x
    ) y
where y.action = 'Start'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution tested in HANA SQL

Same query but excluding the records that are not the min duration

```
CREATE TABLE "TESTSCHEMA"."EVENTS" (ID integer, "user" NVARCHAR(20), "action" NVARCHAR(20), "timestamp" SECONDDATE);

INSERT INTO "TESTSCHEMA"."EVENTS" VALUES (12, 'user1', 'END', '2022-01-01 05:00');
INSERT INTO "TESTSCHEMA"."EVENTS" VALUES (43, 'user1', 'START', '2022-01-01 04:00');
INSERT INTO "TESTSCHEMA"."EVENTS" VALUES (54, 'user1', 'END', '2022-01-01 03:00');
INSERT INTO "TESTSCHEMA"."EVENTS" VALUES (13, 'user1', 'START', '2022-01-01 02:00');
INSERT INTO "TESTSCHEMA"."EVENTS" VALUES (13, 'user1', 'START', '2022-01-01 09:00');

SELECT "ID1","ID2","Start Time","End Time" FROM
(
 select 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s."ID" order by SECONDS_BETWEEN(e."timestamp",s."timestamp") DESC) AS RN,
  s."ID" as "ID1",
  e."ID" as "ID2",
  s."user",
  s."timestamp" as "Start Time",
  e."timestamp" as "End Time",
  SECONDS_BETWEEN(e."timestamp",s."timestamp") AS "Duration"
  from "TESTSCHEMA"."EVENTS" s
left join "TESTSCHEMA"."EVENTS" e on s."user" = e."user"
where s."action" = 'START'
  and e."action" = 'END'
  and s."timestamp" < e."timestamp"
)WHERE RN=1
```